# If v and w are orthogonal vectors and their images f(v), f(w) are orthogonal there exists an isometry we can build with a scalar $\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, isometry

Let V be an inner product space.

$f: V \to V$ and f is linear for factors in $\mathbb C$, $f \neq 0 $

Prove that if $ \langle v, w \rangle = 0 $ then $ \langle f(v), f(w) \rangle = 0 $ for all $v, w \in V$

then there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ so that: $\alpha f: V\to V$ is an isometry.

Which means: $ \langle \alpha f(v), \alpha f(w) \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle $  for all $ v, w \in V$

I'd really appreciate an explanatory answer, because I have no clue at the moment and fizzled around 3 hours with this question.
Have a great start in your week.:)

Comment: As a starting point I would consider a real vector space, and in particular a two-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: Supposed the claim is true, how would you find such an $\alpha$?

Comment: If the claim is true for $\alpha \in \mathbb C$, then following equation holds:

$< \alpha f(v), \alpha f(w) > = < v, w > $ <=> 

$ \lVert \alpha \rVert ^2 * < f(v) , f(w) > = < v, w > $ <=> 

$ < \alpha , \alpha > * < f(v) , f(w) > = < v, w > $ 

But that only tells me something about the norm of $ \alpha $ and I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: That comment looks like a good start now use a vector $v$ for which $f(v) \neq 0$

Comment: Okay:

Because $ f \neq 0 $ there exist $ v \in V $ so that $ f(v) \neq 0 $ 

If v and w are orthogonal the above equation doesn't have any great information for us, because then $< v, w > = 0 $ and therefore $ < f(v), f(w) > = 0 $ and we could use any $ \alpha \in \mathbb C $ 

So we assume that v, w aren't orthogonal and therefore $ < v, w > \neq 0 $ 
Because of: $ \lVert \alpha \rVert ^2 * < f(v), f(w) > = < v, w > \neq 0 $ we know that f(v) and f(w) can't be orthogonal and we can write:

$ \lVert \alpha \rVert ^2 = \frac{ < v, w> }{ < f(v), f(w) > } $

Comment: But I somehow don't get how to go from the Norm to the actual vector $ \alpha $

Comment: $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ so you really mean the modulus $|\alpha|^2$

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if there were other Norms on $ \mathbb C $ than the Euclidian one, that's why I didn't use it. 

Okay, I said that $ \alpha = c + i*d $ and our equation told us that:
$ c^2 + d^2 = \frac{< v, w > } {< f(v) , f(w) > } $ 
This equation has more than one solutions so I set d = 0 and therefore $ \alpha = \sqrt \frac{ < v, w > }{ < f(v), f(w) > } $ 

But if I put this into: $< \alpha f(x) , \alpha f(y) > $ for $ x, y \in V $ I can't seem to get $ < x, y > $ out of it. 

Sorry that I ask so much, it's probably a stupid question but I somehow can't figure this out.

Comment: @Adrian perhaps edit your problem to include your definition of an inner product space. Typically over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ you include conjugate symmetry $\left<a,b\right>=\overline{\left<b,a\right>}$ and linearity which would force what you're considering on $\alpha$ to be the modulus.

Comment: No, we have the typical definition with conjugate symmetry and linearity, I'm just too stupid to calculate it through to the end. Though I keep trying.^^

Thanks a lot by the way for all the help!:)